# Get current time on Android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I want to set up something in my Unity Android application that let's the user pick a time and then sends them a notification at that time and every half hour after if they don't use the app.

I have the Android Native plugin (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10825) installed that takes care of local notifications but don't know how to send local notifications at a specific time. How do I get the current time on the device? Is there a way to do that in Unity?

Comment: Are you programming in C#, right? then DateTime.Now has the current date.

Comment: what is "the Android Native plugin"? would you mind sharing a link?

Comment: @JeanLuc added the link

Comment: have you read and tried this out? https://unionassets.com/android-native-plugin/local-notifications-90

Answer (score 1):

```
 System.currentMilleseconds();
```

will reruen milleseconds since 1970... you can use

```
Calender c = Calender.getInstance();
 c.getItem(Calender.DayInMonth)
```

... BLA BLA BLA

Answer (score 0):

simply use this code to get the current time in android

```
public String getCurrentTime(){
    Time dtNow = new Time();
    dtNow.setToNow();
    return dtNow.format("%H:%M");    // YYYYMMDDTHHMMSS
}
```

you can manipulate the format to suit you